# After install "reboot and select boot device" "or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key"

Tags: system-installation

Every time I install elementary OS it works okay, then after I take out  the flash drive and reboot it pops up saying [what I've written in the title of this question].

Comment: Using Toshiba satellite l15w-b1302

Comment: Have you checked the boot order in your BIOS settings? Perhaps only flash drive is showing up.

Comment: theres hard drive and flash drive  i have flash drive to boot up first but i take it out when it asks restart now or later i click restart and pull it out.

Comment: Add that to the answer

Comment: You could try changing the boot order to hard drive first and then flash drive, perhaps that could fix it?

Comment: it works now lel i haven't looked at this site in a while it works now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install system in UEFI mode, you need to show boot menu devices and select your disk partition with installed Elementary OS.
BUT,
i prefer to install system in LEGACY mode and you will not have any difficulty-